# Processing Json Data in PHP

Tags: php, json, ajax

I´m having problems to process Json Data in PHP via an Ajax call.  I´m reading Json data from a Web Service.

I receive the data via JQuery getJSON method and if I stringify the data I have the following data structure:

```
[{"id":"788","name":"Tunisia","name_es":"Túnez","iso2":"TN","prefix":"216","zones":[{"id":"3805","name":"Beja","code":"31"},{"id":"3806","name":"Ben Arous","code":"13"},{"id":"3807","name":"Bizerte","code":"23"},{"id":"3808","name":"Gabes","code":"81"},{"id":"3809","name":"Gafsa","code":"71"},{"id":"3810","name":"Jendouba","code":"32"},{"id":"3811","name":"Kairouan","code":"41"},{"id":"3812","name":"Kasserine","code":"42"},{"id":"3813","name":"Kebili","code":"73"},{"id":"3815","name":"L'Ariana","code":"12"},{"id":"3814","name":"La Manouba","code":"14"},{"id":"3816","name":"Le Kef","code":"33"},{"id":"3817","name":"Mahdia","code":"53"},{"id":"3818","name":"Medenine","code":"82"},{"id":"3819","name":"Monastir","code":"52"},{"id":"3820","name":"Nabeul","code":"21"},{"id":"3821","name":"Sfax","code":"61"},{"id":"3822","name":"Sidi Bouzid","code":"43"},{"id":"3823","name":"Siliana","code":"34"},{"id":"3824","name":"Sousse","code":"51"},{"id":"3825","name":"Tataouine","code":"83"},{"id":"3826","name":"Tozeur","code":"72"},{"id":"3827","name":"Tunis","code":"11"},{"id":"3828","name":"Zaghouan","code":"22"}]}]
```

As you can see there are keys and values:
"id":"788",
"name":"Tunisia",
"name_es":"Túnez",
"iso2":"TN",
"prefix":"216"

And an optional array called zones with different keys and values:
"zones":[{"id":"3805","name":"Beja","code":"31"},
{"id":"3806","name":"Ben Arous","code":"13"}, 
...

I have two methods to pass different data to two PHP processing files:
countryData(data2[0].name, data2[0].prefix, data2[0].iso2), this function will write to the countries table via Ajax
zoneData(data2[0].zones, data2[0].iso2), this function will write to the zones table via Ajax

Both methods work simultaneously.

I´m having difficulties working with the data2[0].zones array in the PHP file (I don´t manage to check the structure and access the fields).  The main problem I´m having is that I can´t var_dum() or echo() in the php file because if i do so it will not print because the data i need to check is coming from the ajax calls.

Is there something I must do to organize the data before sending it via Ajax which will make things easier in the backend side?

Or perhaps is there a way of printing the data in the server side to check what´s happening?  Or perhaps a method that organizes the received data in way which is easy a methodically easy to work with?

Any ideas are more than welcome.

I live some samples of the code incase it helps:

```
function addZones(data){


    $.getJSON("http:.." + data.codIso, function(data2){
       var myJSON = JSON.stringify(data2);
       console.log("DATA 2: " + myJSON);

       countryData( data2[0].name, data2[0].prefix, data2[0].iso2 )

       zonesData( data2[0].zones, data2[0].iso2 );
    });

}
```

CORRECTION:
Before I send via Ajax has the following format using stringify:
Zones stringify: [{"id":"3924","name":"Abim","code":"UG-317"},{"id":"3925","name":"Adjumani","code":"UG-301"},{"id":"3926","name":"Amolatar","code":"UG-314"},
....

In the backend I have the following:

```
$zones = $_POST['zones'];
$zonesArray =  json_decode($zones);

 $jsondata["success"] = true;
    $jsondata["data"] = array(
      'message' => (string)$zonesArray[0]['name']
    );

header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($jsondata, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

In the Ajax response I get the following error:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0parsererror[object Object]

Comment: One easy way to see what is going on is to take the URL you're using in your AJAX call, if dynamic just console.log it then copy/paste. And browse to it directly and then use var_dump in your AJAX file with the variable you want to look at. Then you'll be able to see any errors or variables printed to the screen.

Comment: You can *log* into a file server side, or you can *print* anything you want, but you inspect the response in your browser's developer tools' network inspector instead.

Comment: @dukedevil294 I have already tried that, but this way I can´t see the data I´m passing via Ajax and that´s what i would like to echo.

Comment: @deceze i need to see the format I´m receiving the data in the server side without responding.  The idea is to be able to prepara the queries from the data I´m receiving.  The main problem I´m having is not being able to access correctly to the zones array in order to do the inserts.